# How can I create my own custom buttons?

Tags: c#, xaml, gdi+, kendo-ui

I'm a fairly new programmer; semi-seasoned.  But I still need a lot of learning.  So I've focused on a few languages.  C# is the big one.

Now I know Visual Studio lets you simply pull a button straight out of the toolbox.  You now have a control; that manipulates that object.

I'd like to get really deep into programming a button for instance.  Create my own custom buttons; Where I can draw the shape, size, gradients, hover effects, glass effects, drop-downs, really get into the nuts and bolts to create these reusable, dynamic, decorative controls.

What is the best starting point? Any advice seasoned developers could share with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a **xaml** `"UserControl"` to your project and make the WPF content of what you wanna render on the control in `"Template"` property. Then you should use some Binding expression to load content and handle events. It's so simple to do that and make whatever custom thing you need in WPF. There is no need to do paint things like .NET 2.

Cheers

Comment: So XAML will allow you to truly create those components?  Kind of like Telerik does with it's RadControls / RadForms?

Comment: Far from it, I can say that after many years, I've never used any components like RadControls or Telerik. WPF has a great environment and structure for doing such a thing. Using XAML in a correct way will give you many things that you've never seen. ;)

Comment: Awesome, that is what I'm looking for. Create custom forms, layouts, controls, buttons, very unique powerful interfaces.  Thanks for the response.